# How to force Apache POI to create a relations file for my header?

Tags: apache-poi, openxml

I've got a very simple file generated by Apache POI, that contains an image and a sentence in the page header, nothing else. The image, while embedded, doesn't display under Word.

I have taken a lot of time to compare the same file generated by Word, removing the differences one by one in order to find the root cause.

Here's the Apache POI-generated file structure:

```
.
├── [Content_Types].xml
├── _rels
├── docProps
│   ├── app.xml
│   └── core.xml
└── word
    ├── _rels
    │   └── document.xml.rels
    ├── document.xml
    ├── footer1.xml
    ├── header1.xml
    ├── media
    │   └── image1.png
    └── settings.xml
```

Here's the `header1.xml` file (stripped a *little* bit):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<w:hdr xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mo="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mac/office/2008/main" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mv="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mac:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14">
    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:jc w:val="left" /></w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:drawing>
                <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0">
                    <wp:extent cx="1193800" cy="635000" />
                    <wp:docPr id="2" name="Picture 2" descr="Generated" />
                    <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
                        <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                            <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                                <pic:nvPicPr>
                                    <pic:cNvPr id="2" name="Generated" />
                                    <pic:cNvPicPr/></pic:nvPicPr>
                                <pic:blipFill><a:blip r:embed="rId2" />
                                    <a:stretch><a:fillRect/></a:stretch>
                                </pic:blipFill>
                                <pic:spPr>
                                    <a:xfrm><a:off x="0" y="0" /><a:ext cx="1193800" cy="635000" /></a:xfrm>
                                    <a:prstGeom prst="rect"><a:avLst/></a:prstGeom>
                                </pic:spPr>
                            </pic:pic>
                        </a:graphicData>
                    </a:graphic>
                </wp:inline>
            </w:drawing>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
</w:hdr>
```

The image XML code is generated by hand using [the solution found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17849834/334493).

The reference ID is relative to what's inside `_rels/document.xml.rels`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
  <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/settings" Target="settings.xml"/>
  <Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image" Target="media/image1.png"/>
  <Relationship Id="rId3" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/header" Target="header1.xml"/>
  <Relationship Id="rId4" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/footer" Target="footer1.xml"/>
</Relationships>
```

So basically insert image `rId2` => `media/image1.png`.

Now with the document generated by Word, there are a lot more files generated, but once striped, this is what it looks like:

```
.
├── [Content_Types].xml
├── _rels
├── docProps
│   ├── app.xml
│   └── core.xml
└── word
    ├── _rels
    │   ├── document.xml.rels
    │   └── header1.xml.rels
    ├── document.xml
    ├── header1.xml
    ├── media
    │   └── image1.png
    └── settings.xml
```

Same files, except for the `_rels/header1.xml.rels`, which contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships>
    <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image" Target="media/image1.png"/>
</Relationships>
```

And the only difference is the relation ID, which is `rId1`, which is taken from `header1.xml.rels`, which points to the image.

Now I'm no expert in OOXML nor Apache POI, but I would like POI to put the header's relations in a separate file. Is it possible?

I also noted that these XML namespaces *need* to be added for the image to be decoded:

```
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing"
xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
```

Update: code uploaded to https://gist.github.com/BenoitDuffez/b132d45747ef8c2e9e7c

Processing:

- the code calls `Exporter#export`
- the `Exporter` class calls through `POIExporter` methods such as `#openDocument`, `#addImage`, etc
- the order of calls is: `createDocument`, `startHeader`, `createParagraph`, `addImage`, `setParagraphAlignment`, `endParagraph`

I attached a full log to the gist.

Comment: How are you adding the image into the file? Normally, POI takes care of adding the relationships between different parts of the document for you

Comment: You're right, POI does the relationship management. I'm adding the image as described in the linked answer in the middle of my question. I just want the relationship to be added to `_rels/headers.xml.rels` instead of the default `_rels/document.xml.rels`.

Comment: Can you post your code? I think I know what you're doing wrong, but since the question you linked to only deals with pictures in the main document not a header I can't be sure...

Comment: I'll try and post it. It's kind of complicated because my software is a document writer, with 2 formats for file writing (PDF/OOXML). See my updated question.

Comment: Need the bit where you add the image data to the file, and the bit where you create the paragraph + add the image reference to it, if nothing else. Even better would be a small, self contained unit test!

Comment: I'll write a unit test if I can't debug this with the full code. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: OK I think I know what's wrong, I use `mXWPFDocument.addPictureData`, so the relation is added to the document. I need to figure out how to do this with the header.

Comment: Call exactly the same thing on the header *as well*, and you should be set. It'll re-use the existing image, but link it to the header. With code I can show you where...

Comment: I posted the code as a gist, see the link in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, I can see you adding the image into the main document itself:

```
// Add the picture data, and get the relationship id
final String blipId = mXWPFDocument.addPictureData(inputStream, pictureType);
// Get the picture number
final int nextPicNameNumber = mXWPFDocument.getNextPicNameNumber(pictureType);
// Add the picture definition
mXWPFDocument.insertPicture(xwpfRun, blipId, nextPicNameNumber, bounds.width, bounds.height);
```

The problem is that you don't appear to be doing the same thing to the header, so it isn't getting associated. Just as with [XWPFDocument](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#addPictureData%28byte%5b%5d,%20int%29), both headers and footers also implement [addPictureData](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#addPictureData%28byte%5b%5d,%20int%29)

So, what you'll need to do is add a new variable of type `XWPFHeaderFooter` to your PoiExporter class. Have this populated by the startHeader and startFooter calls, and nulled by the end ones. Finally, when in the `addImage` method and about to call addPictureData, check if you have a `XWPFHeaderFooter` object. If you do, add the image data to that. If not, add to the main `XWPFDocument` as you do now.

With any luck, that ought to solve it!

Comment: Thanks a lot. But there's still something that bugs me: how to add paragraphs to a header/footer _after_ it is created?

Comment: Various ways! See the [XWPF Header Unit Tests](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/testcases/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/TestXWPFHeader.java) for examples of a few of them :)