# How I can do it to show a image using a url with apache-poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm doing a class to show a image in a document .docx using this example:

[how to add a picture to a .docx document with Apache POI XWPF in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674115/how-to-add-a-picture-to-a-docx-document-with-apache-poi-xwpf-in-java)

But I have one question is possible to use

```
String blipId = paragraphX.getDocument().addPictureData(
    new FileInputStream(
        new File("http://pasarelam.etics.lan/M/Wiki/img/LogoUAB.png")
    ),
    Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
document.createPicture(blipId, 
    document.getNextPicNameNumber(Document.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG),
    200,
    75);
```

How I can do it to show a image using a url?

Comment: Ok, I find the solution.

' InputStream input = new URL("http://pasarelam.etics.lan/M/Wiki/img/LogoUAB.png").openStream();
            String blipId2 = paragraphX.getDocument().addPictureData(input, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);'

Comment: Do you want to fetch the Image at the URL and embed that, or do you want to tell Excel to dynamically load the latest version of that image when the Spreadsheet opens?

Comment: The first and I put the image in a Word document. But the second you told me is interesting... how I can do that?